# Get area code from country chosen automatically

Tags: reactjs

I'm using the npm dependancy "react-country-region-selector" to get countries in my sign-up form, and I want to identify automatically the area code of the country chosen so that the user don't have specify it and can tap directly their phone number.
IS there a way to do so?

Comment: The US has hundreds of area codes. There are literally dozens in downstate New York around New York City, and the same applies to the Los Angeles, California area. There are two in the relatively small area I live in. How would you choose which one to use based on a country region code?

Comment: Tacking on to Ken's comment, the answer is a simple "no."